# Basic vector calculus: Show that $\nabla \vec{r} = \vec{1}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, differentiation

> Show that $\nabla \vec{r} = \vec{1}$

My instructor in my E & M class put the $r$ and $1$ in bold. I am not sure what a bold one means. From my work I get $1ii + 1jj + 1zz$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $1xx + 1yy + 1zz$.

The notation your instructor used simply means
$ \vec 1 = (1, 1, 1).$

Comment: Im trying to get <1, 1, 1> = 1i + 1j + 1k but I keep getting the same answer

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to get the answer $\langle 1,1,1 \rangle$, or are you trying to show that $\langle 1,1,1 \rangle=\hat i + \hat j + \hat k$? Because the latter is just notation.

Comment: From what I recollect, the gradient of a vector is a dyad (tensor), so I think there's something missing (e.g., notation of $\mathbf 1$, the actual operation).

Comment: $\vec{1}$ simply means the unit dyad, which user777777 below demonstrates. See here < https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Unit_dyadic >

Comment: The way you wrote it, I would say it is the divergence of the vector. But this should be 3.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the gradient of a vector field gives a tensor of rank 2: $$\nabla(\mathbf r) = \nabla(x \mathbf{\hat x} + y \mathbf{\hat y} + z \mathbf{\hat z}) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial (x)}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial (x)}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial (x)}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial (y)}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial (y)}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial (y)}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial (z)}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial (z)}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial (z)}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ which is the unit tensor, $\overleftrightarrow 1$, in this case. In general, $$\nabla(\mathbf F) = \nabla(F_x \mathbf{\hat x} + F_y \mathbf{\hat y} + F_z \mathbf{\hat z}) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix} \text{or} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix}$$ depending on the context. This, however, does not seem to be the result that you're trying to show, so I suspect that there's a typo.